# QlikView and Hadoop in same server with Kerberos

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, qlikview

i have a big doubt. In the same server i have running some loader of qlikview and a data lake in hadoop. My qlikview loader consult some "tables" of the data lake using an impala connector (the connector that you can find in the qlikmarkt), but we will have kerberos security in our data lake.

Anybody knows if i will need the special connector that cloudera provides for kerberos? I think that probably kerberos will not affect in local but i dont know, any idea?

Thanks for all

Comment: Ok, you need to have kerberos in the two places.

Comment: What flavor of Kerberos do you plan to use? The regular "MIT Kerberos" that Hadoop supports, or an "Active Directory Kerberos" thru some kind of gateway used to authenticate Linux users against AD?

Comment: If you run QlikStuff on Windows you can have a look at this MicroStrategy tech note: https://community.microstrategy.com/t5/tkb/articleprintpage/tkb-id/database/article-id/423 Then there is the issue of renewing the TGT automatically in the background, with a Scheduled Task and a *keytab* password file.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i have ask to some expert and they say that you need kerberos in all the parts of the server, then you must use the new cloudera connector.